# ReferenceError: mongoose is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am getting ReferenceError: mongoose is not defined. I am new to node please App.js code is below is as shown below. I am not able to solve it by all the answers provided in google.

```
   var express = require('express');
 var app = require('mongoose');
 var path = require('path');
 var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); 
   app.set('view engine', 'jade');

 app.use(logger('dev'));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
   app.use(cookieParser());
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

 app.use('/', index);
 app.use('/users', users);
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
  });

  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb');

  var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  cr   : String,

        });

       var user = mongoose.model('myc', Schema);

    app.get('/view', function(req, res){
     user.find({}, function(err, docs){
      if(err) res.json(err);
    else    res.render('index', {users: docs});
      });
             });


      app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

    res.locals.message = err.message;
     res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    res.status(err.status || 500);
   res.render('error');
  });

 module.exports = app;
```

I am using node version6.11.0 and npm v 5.5.1
How to resolve this? pleas help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install mongoose as a dependency

run this command,

```
$ npm install mongoose --save
```

also replace

```
var app = require('mongoose');
```

to

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure mongoose is installed. Try installing via npm.

`npm install mongoose --save`

Comment: Its installed via npm only

Comment: True and I should have been more clear. Though the answer stands and is obviously accurate, though I was beat by 3 seconds by @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 0):

Replace `var app = require('mongoose');` with `var mongoose = require('mongoose');`. I assume, you already installed mongoose. If not, install it using the command `npm i mongoose --save`

Answer (score 0):

All this answers are in CJ so I would like to show how to connect a MongoDB with ES6 to avert this error:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const connect = async () => {
    try {
      await mongoose.connect(your DB url);
      console.log("Connected to mongoDB.");
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
```